# export typedefs in .NET dlls

Tags: c++-cli

I've written a wrapper for a C++ dll in C++/CLI. Inside the wrapper, I made some typedefs. Is there a way to export these names as .NET classes?

---

Background: the typedef'd classes are some templates. For these templates to work, you need a managed and a native parameter (this is part of the translation). This is impossible for the client of the wrapper to program / know. That's why he needs the different aliases for the used versions of the template.

Comment: Why would you want to export an alias? I suppose you could map the same types with the "using" keyword for readability. Can you provide more detail?

Answer (score 1):

I exchanged the typedefs with some new class definitions that derive from the template. This should work.

Comment: Make sure you also forward the constructors.

Comment: yes - my main problem now is that this introduces cycle references.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have too much information but typedefing should work only on Clr types. Generic classes, maybe but template classes can not ne typedefed. Also among native types, only the ones that are common (the word "common" may not be correct here.) to .net i.e. double, int, char, Char* (not char*) etc.
This code works and introduces a "new" type to clr.

```
namespace example
{
#ifdef _WIN64
  typedef sizeT UInt64
#else 
  typedef sizeT UInt32
#endif
}
```

Now you have size_t of .Net, whose size depends on platform.